# Regular expression for String which should allow <String>(<String>,<String>), pattern in java

Tags: java, regex

I  want to write a regular expression that allows the pattern `<String>(<String>,String),`

That means:

```
Hello(Test,regEx),Hi(RegEx,Verify)   ---- Valid
Hello(,,)                            ---- Invalid
Hello(Test                           ---- Invalid
Hello(Test Test)                     ---- Invalid
```

Comment: What is your attempt ?

Comment: [a-zA-Z0-9][\\(][a-zA-Z0-9][,][a-zA-Z0-9][\\)]

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you if you mess with it a little. I made some assumptions about where whitespace can go.

```
\w+\s*\(\s*\w+\s*,\s*\w+\s*)\s*,?\s*
```

Answer (score 1):

As much as I want to notice that parsing expressions of a programming language using just regular expressions generally does not bode well, I'd also like to make sure you understand that besides a simple symbol, in the call you are parsing one might easily use a literal (`"hello"`) or a compound expression (`I18n.Loc("E_UNKNOWN", error.Message)`).
If you are 100% positive that you could only need the case of

```
<identifier><left-parenthesis><identifier><comma><identifier><right-parenthesis>
```

then a simple `(id)`\(`(id)`,`(id)`\) would do,

where `(id)` is to be replaced with a proper java identifier regex: `[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\d_$]*`

Careful though, as you might also want to exclude all java keywords (like class, int and so on), as they are obviously not valid there as well...